# Python Dictionaries & CSV Values | Check CSV

Tags: python, csv

The `csv` file works fine. So does the `dictionary` but I can't seem to check the values in the `csv` file to make sure I'm not adding duplicate entries. How can I check this? The code I tried is below:

```
    def write_csv():
        csvfile = csv.writer(open("address.csv", "a"))
        check = csv.reader(open("address.csv"))
        for item in address2:
            csvfile.writerow([address2[items]['address']['value'],address2[items]['address']['count'],items, datetime.datetime.now()])


    def check_csv():
        check = csv.reader(open("address.csv"))
        csvfile = csv.writer(open("address.csv", "a"))
        for stuff in address2:
            address = address2[str(stuff)]['address']['value']
            for sub in check:
                if sub[0] == address:
                    print "equals"
                    try:
                        address2[stuff]['delete'] = True
                    except:
                        address2[stuff]['delete'] = True
                else:
                    csvfile.writerow([address2[stuff]['address']['value'], address2[stuff]['address']['count'], stuff, datetime.datetime.now()])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Do you get an error?  If so, what error?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is address2 in check_csv? There are a couple things you'll want to change, but we'll address that when you clarify your question.

Comment: @Keeyai, i'm trying make sure the new items from the `dictionary` `address2` is not already in the `csv` file `address.csv`. If it is already in the `csv` file I want to mark it to be deleted (but not actually delete it) and if it's not in the `csv` then to append the new row. It throws a `key error` from above and I can't figure out why (when each `key` item is tested individually, it works fine)

Comment: Is the key error in address2[items]? Maybe you meant item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV and dict structures are a little wonky - I'd love to know if that is set or if you can change them to be more useful. Here is an example that does basically what you want -- you'll have to change some things to fit your format. The most important change is probably not writing to a file that you are reading - that is going to lead to headaches.

This does what you asked with the delete flag -- is there an external need for this? If not there is almost certainly a better way (removing the bad rows, saving the good rows somewhere else, etc - depends on what you are doing).

Anyway, here is the example. I used just the commented block to create the csv file in the first place, then added the new address to the list and ran the rest. Instead of looping through the file over and over it makes a lookup dict by address and stores the row number, which it then uses to update the delete flag if it is found when it reads the csv file. You'll want to take the prints out and uncomment the last line to actually write the new rows.

```
import csv, datetime

addresses = [
    {'address': {'value': '123 road', 'count': 1}, 'delete': False},
    {'address': {'value': '456 road', 'count': 1}, 'delete': False},
    {'address': {'value': '789 road', 'count': 1}, 'delete': False},

    {'address': {'value': '1 new road', 'count': 1}, 'delete': False},
]

now = datetime.datetime.now()

### create the csv
##with open('address.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
##    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
##    for row in addresses:
##        writer.writerow([ row['address']['value'], row['address']['count'], now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ])

# make lookup keys for the dict
address_lookup = {}
for i in range(len(addresses)):
    address_row = addresses[i]
    address_lookup[address_row['address']['value']] = i

# read csv once
with open('address.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        print row
        # if address is found in the dict, set delete flag to true
        if row[0] in address_lookup:
            print 'flagging address as old: %s' % row[0]
            addresses[ address_lookup[row[0]] ]['delete'] = True

with open('address.csv', 'ab') as csv_file:
    # go back through addresses and add any that shouldnt be deleted to the csv
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for address_row in addresses:
        if address_row['delete'] is False:
            print 'adding row: '
            print address_row
            #writer.writerow([  row['address']['value'], row['address']['count'], now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ])
```

Comment: perfect. It's definitely more for internal testing prior to going live with `django` & `mysql` as you may know there's a nice handy feature called `get_or_create` with objects such as addresses.